# How to make it so that my PyQt5 checkbox can be prechecked from another .py file

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm making a GUI with PyQt5.
I'm very very new to it. I need help.
First i have a stacked widget that I can use to switch between pages.
Right now im trying to make a setings page.

[Settings Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4OqS.png)

I know that putting stacked widgets for changing like "window"/page in pyqt5 might not be the best but ignore if you want to (if its bad give me a suggestion please).

Right now I want to check if the Dark Mode checkbox is enabled.
I have a MainWindow.py and I have a gui.py which is the one that I transformed from a .ui to .py (pyuic5 cmd).
In MainWindow.py I'm handling all of the gui's "commands/buttons".
gui.py is the file with all of the gui imported from qt designer.
I also have settings.config which is the files where I *try* to save the settings.
BTW my main idea was to write when the check box was clicked to save the thing to the .config file (which it does) and then check from MainWindow.py if the text == 'Dark Mode: True'

**The Big Question** How do I make it so the checkbox can be checked from another file (MainWindow.py)?
Also, if not should I change how the gui is handled and stuff.

Heres my code BTW:
The MainWindow.py Script:

```
import sys
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from gui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_win = QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.main_win)

        self.main_win.setWindowTitle("GUI App")

        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.start)

        # Start Screen
        self.ui.startButton.clicked.connect(self.showHomeScreen)
        self.ui.settingsButton.clicked.connect(self.showSettingsScreen)

        # Settings Screen
        self.ui.backStartButton.clicked.connect(self.showStartScreen)

        self.ui.darkModeEnabled.clicked.connect(self.checkDarkMode)

        # Home Screen
        self.ui.backToStartHome.clicked.connect(self.showStartScreen)

    def showHomeScreen(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.home)

    # Start Screen Funcions
    def showStartScreen(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.start)

    # Settings Functions
    def showSettingsScreen(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.settings)

    def checkDarkMode(self):
        if self.ui.darkModeEnabled.isChecked() == True:
            self.f = open('settings.config', 'w')
            self.f.write("Darkmode: True")
            self.f.close()

        if self.ui.darkModeEnabled.isChecked() == False:
            self.f = open('settings.config', 'w')
            self.f.write("Darkmode: False")
            self.f.close()

        for line in open('settings.config', 'r'):
            if line == 'Darkmode: True':
                self.ui.darkModeEnabled.setChecked(True)
                print('Darkmode is on!')
            elif line == 'Darkmode: False':
                self.ui.darkModeEnabled.setChecked(False)
                print('Darkmode is off!')

    def show(self):
        self.main_win.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_win = MainWindow()
    main_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The gui.py script:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(597, 319)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-21, -11, 651, 321))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.start = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.start.setObjectName("start")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.start)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 30, 351, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(48)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.start)
        self.startButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 180, 131, 51))
        self.startButton.setObjectName("startButton")
        self.settingsButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.start)
        self.settingsButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 180, 131, 51))
        self.settingsButton.setObjectName("settingsButton")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.start)
        self.home = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.home.setObjectName("home")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.home)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 30, 351, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(48)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.backToStartHome = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.home)
        self.backToStartHome.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(34, 42, 91, 51))
        self.backToStartHome.setObjectName("backToStartHome")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.home)
        self.settings = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.settings.setObjectName("settings")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.settings)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 0, 431, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(48)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.backStartButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.settings)
        self.backStartButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 91, 31))
        self.backStartButton.setObjectName("backStartButton")
        self.darkModeEnabled = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.settings)
        self.darkModeEnabled.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 130, 111, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.darkModeEnabled.setFont(font)
        self.darkModeEnabled.setObjectName("darkModeEnabled")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.settings)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 597, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start Page"))
        self.startButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.settingsButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Settings"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Home Page"))
        self.backToStartHome.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Back to Start"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Settings Page"))
        self.backStartButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Back to Start"))
        self.darkModeEnabled.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dark Mode"))
```

If you read all of this and know how to fix this please help.
And if you didn't but just know please help.
**Thank You**

Comment: I don't understand what your asking.  Please post more of your code or read [example]

Comment: @alexpdev I edit it and now it has the 2 scripts